# Open Graph Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, html-meta-tag

Criei as seguintes Open Graph tags para poder partilhar paginas dum site:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Tranzao">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="BrainStorm">
<meta property="og:url" content="nome do site">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.google.pt/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_67mx0OLTAhVM6xoKHT5XADYQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mensagenscomamor.com%2Fimagens-de-deus&psig=AFQjCNFNZ_33-_diZiOY1CckXHoXO6Huzw&ust=1494412997941849">
<meta property="article:author" content="Romeu">
```

O botão de partilha ate funciona, contudo não aparece imagem. A única coisa que está correta é o nome do site.

Utilizei a ferramenta de debugger do facebook e lá aparecem vários erros, como por exemplo:

> The 'og:type' property is required, but not presente

Contudo isto não deveria aparecer, pois já tenho uma meta `property` definida, como mostra em cima.

Pelo que percebi no debuger ele não apanha nenhuma tag, por isso deve ser algum erro, mas não sei onde. Também já pus o prefix `og: http://ogp.me/ns#` no head, mas nada, ta tudo na mesma.

Comment: Olá Romeu, tudo bem?
Então, a tag `og:image` não é uma imagem. Ao tentar abrir ele tenta me direcionar para um site. Você poderia adicionar a url do debugger para vermos?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbraincast.azurewebsites.net%2FPensamento%2FDetalhes%3FpensamentoId%3D1 Aqui esta o url do debugger. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda. Já segui abordagens diferentes mas o resultado é sempre o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, mas...

Instalei este package no meu projeto: Skybrud.OpenGraph, depois é só seguir o que diz a documentação, não é complicado.

Contudo isto não funcionou á primeira. Foi ao debugger do facebook e voltava a dar-me os mesmos erros, minutos mais tarde voltei a tentar, não mexi no código, e para meu espanto funcionou.

Espero que isto serva de ajuda para mais alguém.